# How to assigned/enabled connected app in permission set using package.xml

Tags: metadata, connected-apps, permission-sets, package.xml

I have one permission set and one conncted app ,I have enabled this Connected app in permission set ,but when i am retiriving Permissions set not able to retrieve it in Package.

i am doing like below.

```
<types>
    <members>TestPermission</members>
    <name>PermissionSet</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ConnectedApp</name>
</types>
```

but still permission is not coming to permission set metadata in permission set
[image]

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to move the permission of connected app with permission set?? OR are you moving the connected app itself?

Comment: Yes I am trying to move permission of connected app with permission set

Comment: Your XML looks right. Something else is going wrong. The connected app does not have to be mentioned in the Permission Set or anything like that, either. This should work.

Comment: No But if i want associate a connetced app to permission set and need to deploy this metadata to other org.then how can i do it.

Comment: Suppose In other org i have already connetcd app present and just want to enabled it while deploying permission set then how can i do it

Answer (score 3):

SetupEntityAccess is the junction object between Permission Sets and Connected Apps. SetupEntityAccess is a standard object, not metadata, and it does not appear in the Permission Set metadata. Hope that helps.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_setupentityaccess.htm